# sed will not execute as a ssh remote command

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

I'm working on a script that lets me delete old public keys from a server via ssh.
The issue seems to come from the formatting of my ssh command here:

```
ssh -qo ConnectTimeout=20 "${user_ssh}@${ip}" "sed -ein \"s|ssh-rsa\s${fingerprint}\s\(.*\)|#---> deleted by public-key-remover.sh. USER:\1|g\" $key_dir || exit 67"
```

$fingerprint is the fingerprint of the rsa public key.

$key_dir is the location of the public key file.

I made sure $key_dir does exists but it's still printing out following error:

```
sed: can't read s|ssh-rsa\sAAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCDlMyH7CX5ckyspCDx8pqzLv41OM0xjlrSeHhi8gz+6jXepaWDtcrlGzkieN3oOK+uUJKT5Jz8uSRBoTfr20tTLLHklRASoWiy7EvACwqfClRVnC67KBWKWlsIDLBGC3KDkJQbYD8ovDP6svy7xBMW0J1RWnQW/RqaCZ9udFMzh5KUbCCm360eVNnFq7fAR//ZeUHNlTGFfSl/WfxkjacAAfKGjtnxYHfo8N/IGP9rbGoX/nlU8XOr2y9uHkVHt+ghG8/wnZo1quUua8JbjMOv6Ygu40Qe9E5pXKOZr1v1RkvMrNOoZ9O8KNvVt7L5+0TvM2NG7AK51qo9ZpHNPr2b\s\(.*\)|#---> deleted by public-key-remover.sh. USER:\1|g: No such file or directory
```

Since I'm very new to bash, I would love some assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Main issue

The main issue here is that `-e` in `sed -ein …` is an option that requires an option-argument, a sed script to be executed. `in` happens to be a valid sed script and is taken as such. What follows is then interpreted as path(s) to file(s) to be processed. As if the command on the remote side was `sed -e in …`.

I'm not sure it's the only problem, but I'm sure this is why your `sed` interpreted `s|ssh-rsa…` as a path.

If you want to pass `-n` and `-e` options in a compact form then `-e` must be the last one because it requires an option-argument (`-n` doesn't). The option-argument (i.e. your sed script) must immediately follow:

```
sed -i -ne …
```

I separated `-i` because `-isomething` has meaning (possibly different than `-i something`) and you apparently don't want it here, you want `-i`.

A straightforward way is to specify the options one by one:

```
sed -i -n -e …
```

but I really doubt you want `-n`. Your sed script does not explicitly print anything, so with `-n` it will be silent. This means with `-i -n` your sed script will wipe out the content of the file(s).

Note if you tried `sed -e -i …`, then `sed` would complain about `-` being an unknown command, which would be a very different error than what you got. It's because `-i` is not a valid sed script, while your `in` accidentally is.

---

#### Broader picture

There are few conventions we can observe here:

1. `-n` option of `sed` neither requires not accepts an option-argument, another option can follow `n` inside a single argument starting with `-`. `sed -nwhatever` is equivalent to `sed -n -whatever` and the meaning of `-whatever` depends on what `-w` means to `sed`. The convention that `-abc` means `-a -b -c` is quite common for options that don't require option-arguments.
2. `-e` option of `sed` requires an option-argument. `sed -ewhatever` is equivalent to `sed -e whatever`. This convention is quite common for options that require option-arguments.
3. `-i` option of GNU `sed` may or may not take an option-argument. When you want to specify one, you need to concatenate it with `-i`. `-iwhatever` is not equivalent to `-i whatever` nor to `-i -whatever`. This convention is not so common. Note the option is not portable. The `sed` you're using may or may not be GNU `sed`. Compare this thread: [*`sed -i` empty argument compatibility issue*](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2021-March/293236.html).

   > Unfortunately that is a GNU sed extension and use of it is
   > intrinsically not portable usage. And the FreeBSD use of `-i` is a
   > similar but slightly incompatible usage. The `-i` option is not
   > specified by POSIX and so any use of it is non-standard by
   > definition.

   `-n` and `-e` are [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

There may be other conventions. Unfortunately manuals are rarely helpful in learning what tool follows what conventions of this type. Often good tools that do follow common conventions don't bother stating (in their manuals) that they do, maybe because "everyone should follow, it's obvious". And not-so-good tools often don't bother stating that they don't follow because they don't care; if they cared, they would follow in the first place. This is my impression, my guess. Then there are tools that don't even follow the convention of starting options with a dash (for various reasons).

My point is you can learn respective options from `man sed`, `man ls` or `man du`, but the fact you can do `ls -hls` or `du -hms` is not explicitly documented *there*. Acknowledge the common conventions, try them with tools that are new for you. Many will follow, some may not (or not fully). When in doubt, specify options as separate arguments.

---

#### Side note

Some values of `$key_dir` will be problematic. Keep in mind the remote shell will interpret the whole string again (what if `$key_dir` expands to a string with spaces? or with `"`? `'`? `$(reboot)`?). If your local shell is Bash then use `${key_dir@Q}`. Bash will expand the variable in a special way, so after the result is parsed in a (remote) shell, it becomes the original string again. The expanded string is properly quoted and/or escaped.

Answer (score 0):

From [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048482/29097), answer by [Javi M.](https://askubuntu.com/users/139772/javi-m)

> ```
> idssh=$(awk '{print $2}' ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
> ssh $remote "sed -i '\#$idssh#d' .ssh/authorized_keys"
> ```

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else and also reference their name. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: @DavidPostill that's not required from Creative Commons _"Additionally, you may satisfy the attribution requirement by providing a link to a place where the attribution information may be found."_ I attributed the work as the license required, and made no presentation that it was mine. You can't legally attribute work as requested, and commit plagiarism in the same act.

Comment: You didn't **block quote the cited text** - which *is* a requirement regardless of the licence. And **Always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link to it**.

Comment: I did **not** accuse you of plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

The `-i` option to sed takes an extension for the backup file, so don't bundle that option with others.

Also, `-n` stops sed from printing lines, so you'll end up with an empty file.

Embedded backslashes should be escaped.

The `-E` option means parentheses don't need to be escaped.

Try this (with extra newlines for added readability)

```sh
ssh -qo ConnectTimeout=20 "${user_ssh}@${ip}" "
    sed -i -E 's|ssh-rsa\\s${fingerprint}\\s(.*)|#---> deleted by public-key-remover.sh. USER:\\1|g' '$key_dir' || exit 67
"
```